# If I quit after 2 days without filling paperwork can my boss just keep the money

Tags: resignation

I worked at a nail shop and after the first day I knew this wasn't for me. I've been in this type of job before but since then I've moved to more high end spas and prefer that. The reason I decided to work at a shop again(I have another job at the same time) is cuz I have lots of spare time since my main job is only part time. But by the end of the first day I knew in the long run it just wouldn't be worth the time and money so I didn't bother filling out an paperwork since I knew I'd quit. So I tell the boss I'm quitting the end of day 2 and he's upset and disappointed that I didn't try for longer but he tells me I need to fill everything out and he can't just pay me a check. Ok fine. But I know this job will make a dent in my resume making it look bad only working 2 days then quitting. And if he gets my SS# ect even if I don't mention it in resumes future employers still might be able to find it.
So my question is since I haven't filled anything out and he doesn't have documents ect can he just...keep the money? I don't NEED it and if we can all just pretend this never even happened that would be fine and if I have to do 2 days of labor free in order to not bust my resume and have employers ask questions thats fine(just a nail salon I know!!!) also can he just count me a contracted labor

Comment: You mention "SS#" which I assume is "social security number" which implies that this is in the United States.  If so, tagging the location is helpful.  No employer is going to be able to find out your employment history from your social security number.  You are free to fill out the paperwork, get two days of pay, and omit this from your resume.  No one will know or care.  Plenty of people leave side jobs off their resume if they don't add any valuable skills.

Comment: I‘ll never understand why people think resumes are absolute truths inscribed in stone...just do the paperwork, forget about it.

Comment: Next time try to work for a day or two before accepting the job. Is the hassle worth two day's money?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler That might not be legal depending on the labor laws where OP is.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on laws in your country.

However, employers probably do need paperwork so they can add you to payroll and pay you. A company can't just give out money, everything must be recorded for tax purposes.

I don't know which laws exactly (IR35 in UK), but in some countries there are laws to prevent employers paying full-time staff as contractors or freelancers, as tax is different. Paying you as a contractor when you were a full-time employee could possibly be tax avoidance.

A resume can be selective information. You don't list a 2 day job on it, and if it's the only time it happened, and an employer found it somehow I cant imagine they would read much into it.

Answer (score 3):

If it worries you.

Ask your boss just to forget it, and ignore anything that isn't agreement. No one is going to go to any trouble over this.